# How to avoid org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

When a method is annotated with @Transactional and there is an runtime exception, spring eats the exception and throws:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

How do I avoid this "general" exception and propagate the original exception, but keeping the rollback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException:
>   Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as
>   rollback-only

It mostly happens if you have an outer `@Transactional` method calls an inner `@Transactional` method. When the inner method throws an exception , but the outer method catches this exception and return normally, Spring is confused and don't know if it should rollback or commit the transaction  since both methods contradict with each other. (Inner method says it wants to rollback but the outer method says it want to commit)

So , check if there are any outer `@Transactional` methods that catch the exception. If yes , re-throw that exception from the outer method such that the whole transaction will rollback.

Comment: I am catching the Exception in the outer class which just says "UnexpectedRollbackException", but I want to know why the inner class is throwing an exception. how to make the inner class not rollback?

Comment: You can configure `noRollbackFor` of  the `@Transactional` of the inner method to define which exception that you do not want to rollback

Comment: @KenChan How to do this? I tried adding the `rollbackFor = Exception.class` in the inner or outer method, but none seem to work. I just want to do the rollback and ignore that exception.