# Calling @Transactional Method from original @Transactional method causing rollback issue in same class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I currently have a use case, where I where if my user manually inserts a data file to be read into the database I need to check if the data exists in the DB. If it does, I want to delete it and then process and save the new file. The problem with this is my methods are marked @Transactional so even though the delete methods are ran, they aren't committed before the save method is called which violates a unique constraint casuing the rollback.

I have tried every level of propagation and also tried splitting them up into two separate transactions where my controller calls them one by one and they don't call each other.

ERROR: `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`

CODE:

```
 @Transactional
  public void saveAllPositionData(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    log.info("Parsing position data...");
    ParsingResult parsingResult = positionParser.parse(is);
    if (!parsingResult.getPositions().isEmpty()) {
      LocalDate businessDate = parsingResult.getPositions().get(0).getBusinessDate();
      overwriteData(businessDate);
    }

    try {
      positionRepo.saveAll(bpsParsingResult.getPositions()); // UNIQUE CONSTRAINT FAILS HERE CAUSING ROLLBACK
      priceRepo.saveAll(parsingResult.getPrices());

      for (PositionTable position : parsingResult.getPositions()) {
        if (position.getNumberOfMemos() > 0) memoRepo.saveAll(position.getCorrespondingMemos());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn("Invalid data returned from BPS parsing job: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED) // Tried Propagation.* and no Annotation
  public void overwriteData(LocalDate businessDate) {
    if (memoRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
              "Memo record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
              businessDate);
      memoRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
    if (positionRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
          "Position record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
          businessDate);
      positionRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
    if (priceRepo.countByBusinessDate(businessDate) > 0) {
      log.warn(
          "Price record(s) found by {} business date. Existing data will be overridden.",
          businessDate);
      priceRepo.deleteByBusinessDate(businessDate);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnexpectedRollbackException` usually happens when an inner `@Transactional` method throws exception but the outer `@Transactional` method catch this exception but not re-throw it.(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346702/how-to-avoid-org-springframework-transaction-unexpectedrollbackexception/56349984#56349984) for more details). Methods on the `JpaRepository` actually has `@Transactional` annotated on it. Now in `saveAllPositionData()` , some method calls on the `JpaRepository` throw exception but you catch it and not rethrow it so it causes `UnexpectedRollbackException`.

Also , `@Transactional` method does not work if you self calling it from the inner class. That means `@Transactional` on `overwriteData()` does not have effect in your codes. (See Method visibility and `@Transactional` section in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for more detail)

> The problem with this is my methods are marked @Transactional so even
> though the delete methods are ran, they aren't committed before the
> save method is called which violates a unique constraint casuing the
> rollback

You can try to call `flush()` on the `JpaRepository` after calling the delete method. It will apply all the pending SQL changes collected so far to the DB but will not commit the transaction. So only the transaction involved will see the records are deleted such that when you insert the data in the same transaction later , you should not encounter unique constraint violation .

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `overwriteData()` (@Transactional) from the transactional method `saveAllPositionData()` a new transaction was not created but it was executed in the same transaction. This means just like you said

> even though the delete methods are run, they aren't committed before the save method is called which violates a unique constraint causing the rollback.

The following illustrates the above situation, where UserService is a class and invoice is a transactional method which the createPDF inner method which is also transactional.

[image: transactional calsss proxy]

> Spring creates that transactional UserService proxy for you, but once
> you are inside the UserService class and call other inner methods,
> there is no more proxy involved. This means, no new transaction for
> you.

One way to get around this is [self-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280460/spring-self-injection-for-transactions/43282215) or [here](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-transactional-mistakes-everyone-did-31418e5a6d6b)

Another is to keep both the methods in different class.